# Automatic creation of the hive tables on cosmos

Tags: fiware, cosmos, fiware-cygnus

I have an Orion context broker and i use cygnus(0.6) to send data to my cosmos account.
Cygnus creates correctly the txt file with the data on my cosmos, but it does not create
the tables for hive. I would query my data through an hive client.
Is there a configuration paramater to set in cygnus.conf to do that?
How can i solve?

Comment: Same problem here. Cygnus says `Creating Hive external table=...` but it does not show when querying hive.

Comment: New issue added: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/issues/323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself with the same issue and found the problem. Check this: [Cygnus release/0.6.0 does not create Hive extended tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583944/cygnus-release-0-6-0-does-not-create-hive-extended-tables)

Comment: As discussed at [github](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/issues/323), we will maintain the replacement of the Flume's libthrift library, from 0.7 to 0.9.1 (which is indeed made automatically if you install through RPM).A techdebt issue will be created as well in order to analyze your proposal of simply add the 0.9.1 version of the library to Cygnus own libs.