# Cygnus release/0.6.0 does not create Hive extended tables

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I'm running a cygnus instance in a Fi-Lab vm. I've compiled it from branch release/0.6.0. Everything is working except that Hive extended tables for context updates are not created. Cygnus is succesfully receiving updates from Orion, they are forwarded to Cosmos and the HDFS files are created.

The cygnus log says `Creating Hive external table=...` and does not raise any error. Then, if I log into the cosmos head node, I can see the HDFS files created, but if I use the Hive console, the tables are not there.

If I type `SHOW TABLES;` in the Hive console, I can see some tables that end with `_row` and `_column`, so I guess it is working for others.

Any hint? Should I use another version of cygnus?

Comment: New issue added: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/issues/323

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the problem. Flume is using libthrift 0.7 but cygnus needs 0.9. The solution is in the README (at the end of section `Installing Cygnus and its dependencies (from sources)`) but I skipped it. You have to manually overwrite the jar file in the Flume bin distribution with the 0.9 version.

Comment: As discussed at [github](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/issues/323), we will maintain the replacement of the Flume's libthrift library, from 0.7 to 0.9.1 (which is indeed made automatically if you install through RPM).A techdebt issue will be created as well in order to analyze your proposal of simply add the 0.9.1 version of the library to Cygnus own libs.